# how to get data only from vault query

Tags: blockchain, corda

I am using java client for doing vault query in corda, getting complete vault as an output of vault query.
Want to know how to fetch **data field** from this json. Part of the result look like this

```
{
    "states": [
        {
            "state": {
                "data": {
                    "accountId": "1",
                    "value": 200,
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a SpringBoot question; here's how you do it:

1. Let's say you have a state (`MyState`) with the following attributes:

   - issuer: Party
   - accountId: String
   - value: int
2. Inside your `clients` module (i.e. webserver module) create a response model class for your state; it's a simple class that has the attributes that you want to return in your JSON object:

```java
public class MyStateResponseModel {
    // Notice that I defined "issuer" as a String,
    // because I want my response only to return the name;
    // not the full "Party" object
    private String issuer;
    private String accountId;
    private int value;

    // Add getters and setters.
}
```

3. Create a response model mapper for the above class:

```java
@Component
public class MyStateResponseModelMapper extends ModelMapper {
    PropertyMap<MyState, MyStateResponseModel> map;

    public MyStateResponseModelMapper() {
        map = new PropertyMap<MyState, MyStateResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                map().setIssuer(source.getIssuer().getName().toString());
                map().setAccountId(source.getAccountId());
                map().setValue(source.getValue());                
            }
        };
    }
}
```

4. Now inside your controller class where you have the code of your API:

```java
// Define an instance of the mapper; it will get injected by SpringBoot.
private final MyStateResponseModelMapper myStateResponseModelMapper;

// Constructor injection.
public MyController(MyStateResponseModelMapper myStateResponseModelMapper) {
    this.myStateResponseModelMapper = myStateResponseModelMapper;
}

// Your API.
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
private ResponseEntity<MyStateResponseModel> getMyState(/*some request params*/) {
    // You do some query or run a flow that returns an instance
    // of "MyState" called "myState".
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .body(myStateResponseModelMapper.map(myState, MyStateResponseModel.class));
}
```